# Bot Framework Composer HTTP request Error

Tags: botframework, azure-logic-apps, bot-framework-composer

I am developing chatbot in **Bot framework composer**. There, I need to call **Azure logic app** to **send an email using using bot framework composer HTTP request**. I did needed configuration **but doesn't work.** Refer **attachments** for more details. **Please find attached screenshots for more details.**

**Error Code**

```
{“statusCode”: 400,
“reasonPhrase”: “Bad Request”,
“headers”: {
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"x-ms-ratelimit-burst-remaining-workflow-reads": "19999",
"x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-workflow-download-contentsize": "1073741824",
"x-ms-ratelimit-time-remaining-directapirequests": "99999999",
"x-ms-request-id": "southeastasia:4b634b23-3f4f-4acc-9ac7-9ddf3b5534c5",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
"Date": "Fri, 09 Apr 2021 12:29:03 GMT"},
“content”: {
"error": {
"code": "TriggerRequestMethodNotValid",
"message": "The HTTP method for this request is not valid: expected 'Post' and actual 'GET'."}}}
```

**Below shows Request Body JSON schema in Azure logic app**

```js
{
    "properties": {
        "account": {
            "properties": {
                "ID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "address": {
                    "properties": {
                        "city": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "country": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "number": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "postalCode": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "state": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "street": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**Below shows Bot framework composer Body**

```js
{
   "account": {
      "name": "Contoso",
      "ID": "12345",
      "address": {
         "number": "1234",
         "street": "Anywhere Street",
         "city": "AnyTown",
         "state": "AnyState",
         "country": "USA",
         "postalCode": "11111"
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is identified in your error response json payload:

```
"message": "The HTTP method for this request is not valid: expected 'Post' and actual 'GET'."}}}
```

Change your HTTP method to be `POST` instead of `GET` and try once again.